# Unable to locate factory for [App\Models\User] when running test in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test my app using testing in laravel. But I have an error, whenever I run the test using php artisan test it always say `Unable to locate factory for [App\Models\User]`. I can't figured out why this is happening

here is my test code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class Fish extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function test_authenticated_users_can_access_home()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->actingAs($user);

        $response = $this->get('/home')->assertOk();
    }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

        ...
```

UserFactory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
    
    ...
}
```

any help would be very appreciated, thank you
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your UserFactory class, I assume you are using Laravel 8.

The new way to call factories in Laravel 8 is

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
```

instead of the old way

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
```

I think you mixed Laravel 8 and 7 syntax in your ProjectFactory. I would recommend to delete your ProjectFactory  and recreate it on Laravel 8 basis with the PHP artisan command: `php artisan make:factory ProjectFactory`. Then you would call the factory like this:

```
$project = Project::factory()->create();
```

Make sure your Project model uses the hasFactory; trait for this to work.

Comment: Thank you this worked.  yeah, I'm using Laravel 8 and following tutorial for Laravel 5.8